# Does GA treat goal steps uniquely or all of them are counted?

Tags: google-analytics

Let's assume I've set up a goal on GA which consists of 2 steps:

1. Open registration popup (required; custom pageview)
2. Successful registration (destination; custom pageview)

Now, let's say **user A** opens the registration popup 5 times and registers. Then, **user B** opens the popup 1 time and leaves.

What will be the number of **step 1** completions shown in GA report - 6 or 2? In other words, will I see only unique step completions or all of them, regardless of how many times they occurred?

I would say the conversion rate needs all the data (in this case: popup opens) to be of any use. Am I correct?

Comment: The question is moot since goals do never consist of multiple steps. Steps are applied to the (funnel) visualization, not to the conversion. "Required" means that users that did not complete this step will not be included in the visualization, it does not mean their goal conversions do not count.  So for conversion tracking the only relevant thing is what you entered in goal details, this will be counted once per session. Plus, this should really go to webmasters.stackexchange.com (not code involved).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense. Sorry for not being detailed enough: of course the step 1 is added to funnel.

Comment: @EikePierstorff One question though: If I already have a registration goal but for some part of my application I need to know how many users registered via specific popup, do I create a new goal with the same destination and a funnel step, OR do I simply add a required funnel step to the existing goal? UPDATE: I guess separate goals would be better, because I can have more funnels to specify in the future, so in the end I will end up creating new ones.